# I deleted the new key generated upon installation on a new laptop, but now Enigmail can't import the old key

Tags: enigmail

I installed Enigmail on a new laptop, and made the mistake of letting it generate a key pair for me. I realised my mistake, and deleted the new key. But now when I try to import the key from my old laptop, it says:

> You have no key (...my new key ID here...) which matches this revocation
>   certificate!
>
> If you have lost your key, you must import it (e.g. from a keyserver)
>   before importing the revocation certificate!

But as far as I can tell, the new key never made it to the server. So how do I tell Enigmail to just forget the new key? Or am I misunderstanding the problem completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the file you're trying to import *is not your key,* but an unrelated file that you found in the new laptop's `.gnupg` folder.

The only thing it contains is an "emergency" revocation that can be used to mark the key as unusable. (It is meant for use in situations where the public key *was* sent to keyservers, but you later lost the private key and don't want others to use it for sending mail anymore.)

Examine the file you're importing, using a text editor and/or the `gpg` command-line tool. For example, when you run `gpg < your-key-backup.txt`, it should show your old key ID.

You can skip Enigmail altogether and use `gpg --import < your-key-backup.txt`.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I looked at the file, and it said "Comment: This is a revocation certificate". Thank you! *Sidles away looking sheepish...*